# Python Web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am 12 days old into Python and web scraping and managed to write my first ever automation script. Please review my code and point out blunders If any.

What do I want to achieve?

I want to scrape all chapters of each Novel in each category and post it on a WordPress blog to test. Please point out anything that I missed, and is mandatory to run this script on the WordPress blog.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


r = get(site,
        headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
category = soup.findAll(class_="search-by-genre")

# Getting all categories
categories = []
for link in soup.findAll(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$')):
    print("Category:", link.text)
    category_link = link['href']
    categories.append(category_link)


# Getting all Novel Headers
for category in categories:
    r = get(category_link,
            headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    Novels_header = soup.findAll(class_="top-novel-header")


    # Getting Novels' Title and Link
    for Novel_names in Novels_header:
        print("Novel:", Novel_names.text.strip())

        Novel_link = Novel_names.find('a')['href']

        # Getting Novel's Info
        r = get(Novel_link, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        Novel_divs = soup.findAll(class_="chapter-chs")

        # Novel Chapters
        for articles in Novel_divs:
            article_ch = articles.findAll("a")
            for chapters in article_ch:
                ch = chapters["href"]


                # Getting article
                r = get(ch, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
                title = soup.find(class_="block-title")
                print(title.text.strip())
                full_article = soup.find("div", {"class": "desc"})

                # remove ads inside the text:
                for ads in full_article.select('center, small, a'):
                    ads.extract()

                print(full_article.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Naming

Variable names should be `snake_case`, and should represent what they are containing. I would also use `req` instead of `r`. The extra two characters aren't going to cause a heartache.

## Constants

You have the same headers dict in four different places. I would instead define it once at the top of the file in `UPPER_CASE`, then just use that wherever you need headers. I would do the same for `site`.

## List Comprehension

I would go about collecting categories in this way:

```
categories = [link['href'] for link in soup.findAll(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$'))]
```

It's shorter and utilizes a quirk in the python language. Of course, if you want to print out each one, then add this just after:

```
for category in categories:
    print(category)
```

Also, it seems like you assign `category_link` to the last element in the list, so that can go just outside the list comprehension.

## Save your assignments

Instead of assigning the result of `soup.find` to a variable, then using it in a loop, simply put that `soup.find` in the loop. Take a look:

```
for articles in soup.findAll(class_="chapter-chs"):
    for chapters in articles.findAll("a"):
        ....
```

---

As a result of the above changes, you code would look something like this:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"}
SITE = "https://readlightnovel.org/"

req = get(SITE, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
category = soup.findAll(class_="search-by-genre")

categories = [link['href'] for link in soup.findAll(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$'))]
category_link = categories[-1]

# Getting all Novel Headers
for category in categories:
    req = get(category_link, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    novels_header = soup.findAll(class_="top-novel-header")


    # Getting Novels' Title and Link
    for novel_names in novels_header:
        print("Novel:", novel_names.text.strip())

        novel_link = novel_names.find('a')['href']

        # Getting Novel's Info
        req = get(novel_link, headers=HEADERS)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

        # Novel Chapters
        for articles in soup.findAll(class_="chapter-chs"):
            for chapters in articles.findAll("a"):
                ch = chapters["href"]

                # Getting article
                req = get(ch, headers=HEADERS)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
                title = soup.find(class_="block-title")
                print(title.text.strip())
                full_article = soup.find("div", {"class": "desc"})

                # remove ads inside the text:
                for ads in full_article.select('center, small, a'):
                    ads.extract()

                print(full_article.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can even get rid of the regular expressions. I prefer to use the BS4 functions.

Instead of:

```
categories = [link['href'] for link in soup.findAll(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$'))]
```

This statement is equivalent using a **CSS selector**:

```
categories = [link['href'] for link in soup.select("a[href*=\/category\/]")]
```

That means: fetch all the `a href` tags that contain text `/category/` (escaped).